# configuring ehcache for distuibuted caching

Tags: java, ehcache

I want to use ehcacheas distributed ehcache.By distributed i mean i have number of appserver each having its own ehcache and if i put/update a object in one appserver cache all other caches(in other app servers) must automtically synchronize /update.

Now i dont want the address(hostname) of all other caches  to be hardcoded in some config.
Because i can deploy my code in multiple boxes and new boxes can be added at any time and i dont want to modify the config file in all machines.

Can i pull the config file remotely?
Can i add list of servers in form of ip range? or network host class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/) if you don't want to implement it by your own. You can find a sample [here](http://blog.retep.org/2011/09/29/362/).